# Command testing verbose output, can not pass option -v/--versbose into test

Tags: php, symfony, console, phpunit

Made the console command:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $consultations = $this->getContainer()->get('consultation.service')->setConsultationsCompleted();

    if ($consultations) {
        $output->writeln("=== Consultations has been completed ===");
    } else {
        $output->writeln("=== There are no overdue consulations ===");
    }

    foreach ($consultations as $consultation) {
        $output->writeln($consultation->getId(), OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_VERBOSE);
    }
}
```

And test:

```
public function testExecute()
{
    $this->application->add(new CompleteConsultationsCommand());

    $consultations = $this->em->getRepository('ODConsultationBundle:Consultation')->findPastConsultations();

    $command = $this->application->find('consultations:complete');
    $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
    $commandTester->execute([
        'command'  => $command->getName(),
        '--verbose' => true
    ]);

    $output = $commandTester->getDisplay();
    $this->assertContains('Consultations has been completed', $output);
    $this->assertContains($consultations[0]->getId(), $output);
}
```

The second assert does not work. Does not see the information. What am I doing wrong?

**PS**
`$output->writeln($consultation->getId(), OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_VERBOSE);` this line does not display this information without the `--verbose` flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead:

```
$commandTester->execute([
    'command'  => $command->getName(),
    '--verbose' => true
]);
```

It is necessary to use:

```
$commandTester->execute([
    'command'  => $command->getName()
], [
    'verbosity' => OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_VERBOSE
]);
```

Comment: That is because --verbose are no arguments of the command but the application. Just as additional info, there are more like --version IIRC.